# Force a statement to visually write to a file slowly

Tags: php, python, ruby

I have a want to take a `File.open('somefile', 'w+')` and make it read a file, take one line of text at a time, and visually write it slowly in another file. The reason I ask this question is because I can find nothing that does this already in code, nor can I find anything that actually controls the speed of how fast a program writes on the computer. I know that this can be simulated in a program such as Adobe Aftereffects so long as you provide a cursor after a character and the visual effect doesn't take place too quickly, but I've got 4,000 lines of code that I want to iterate over and can't afford to do this manually. This effect can also be achieved with a Microsoft Macro, but this requires it to be manually entered into the macro with no option of copy and paste.

-solutions preferred in Python, Ruby, and PHP-

Comment: When you say "visually write it slowly in another file", do you mean simulate (slow) keystrokes? Because unless you are constantly reloading/tailing the file, you won't even notice it.

Comment: Yes, I mean simulate keystrokes. I was thinking a loop and a file write would do the trick, but it wouldn't show up in the file until the file is completely written and I can't find an option to forcibly wait on a statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some serious testing, I have finally developed a piece of code that will do the very thing I want. Tom Lord gave me some new words to use in my search terms "simulate typing" and this led me to `win32ole` with its `SendKeys` function. Here is a code that will iterate over all the characters in a file and print them out exactly as they were saved while simulating typing. I will see about making this into a gem for future use.

```
require 'win32ole'

wsh = WIN32OLE.new("WScript.Shell")
wsh.Run("Notepad.exe")
while not wsh.AppActivate("Notepad")
  sleep 1
end

def fileToArray(file)
    x = []
    File.foreach("#{file}") do |line|
        x << line.split('')
    end
    return x.flatten!
end

tests = fileToArray("readfrom.txt")

x = 0
while x <= tests.length
    send = tests[x]
    wsh.SendKeys("#{send}")
    x += 1
    sleep 0.1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood properly, what you are trying to achieve, here you go:

```
input = File.read('readfrom.txt', 'r')
File.open('writeto.txt', 'w+') do |f|
  input.chars.each do |c|
    f.print(c)  # print 1 char
    f.flush     # flush the stream
    sleep 1     # sleep
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one quick and dirty way of doing it in Python.

```
from time import sleep

mystring= 'My short text with a newline here\nand then ensuing text'

dt = 0.2 #0.2 seconds
for ch in mystring:
    with open('fn_out','w+') as f:
        f.write(ch)
        f.flush()
    sleep(dt)
```

`f.flush()` will result in updating the file with the changes.

One could make this more elaborate by having a longer pause after each newline, or a variable timestep `dt`.

To watch the change one has to repeatedly reload the file, as pointed out by [@Tom Lord](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1954610/tom-lord) so you could run something like this beforehand to watch it in the terminal:

```
watch  -n 0.1 cat fn_out
```